# How can I select an object in Illustrator while using the eyedropper tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, eyedropper

While trying to make a low poly vector portrait, I have to select multiple objects (one by one) while using the eyedropper tool.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or trick that may help me speed up the process?

Answer (score 2):

With the Eyedropper tool active, holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><sup>*</sup> will allow you to select objects. Adding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to that will allow you to select multiple object (exactly as it does with the Selection tool).

---

*<sup>*</sup>on OS X at least, so I assume <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows does the same, as with most Adobe shortcuts.*